# Creating Cartesian Product DataFrame without maxing Memory

Tags: python, pandas

I have several dataframes, from which I'm creating a cartesian product (on purpose!)

After this, I'm exporting the result to disk.

I believe the size of the resulting dataframe could exceed my memory footprint, so I'm wondering is there a way that I can chunk this so that the dataframe doesn't need to all be in memory at the same time?

Example Code:

```
import pandas as pd

def create_list_from_range(r1,r2): 
    if (r1 == r2): 
        return r1 
    else: 
        res = [] 
        while(r1 < r2+1 ): 
            res.append(r1) 
            r1 += 1
        return res

# make a list of options
color_opt = ['red','blue','green','orange']
dow_opt = create_list_from_range(1,7)
hod_opt = create_list_from_range(0,23)

# turn each list into a dataframe
df_color = pd.DataFrame({'color': color_opt})
df_day = pd.DataFrame({'day_of_week': dow_opt})
df_hour = pd.DataFrame({'hour_of_day': hod_opt})

# add a dummy columns to everything so I can easily do a cartesian product
df_color['dummy']=1
df_day['dummy']=1
df_hour['dummy']=1

# now cartesian product... cascading
merge1 = pd.merge(df_day, df_hour, on='dummy')
FINAL = pd.merge(merge1, df_color, on='dummy')

FINAL.to_csv('FINAL_OUTPUT.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try building up individual rows using `itertools.product`. In your example, you could do this as follows:

```py
from itertools import product

prod = product(color_opt, dow_opt, hod_opt)
```

You can then get a number of rows and append them to an existing csv file using
`df.to_csv("file", mode="a")`